# Etymological History of Satana in Koine Greek

Tags: greek, word-study, etymology

Can someone point me to an academic book on the etymological root of “satanas” (G4567)? Did it originate in the LXX when translating Job? Was *satanas* used extensively in Greco-Roman literature in antiquity?

Comment: A typical Greek source to consult is [Kittel](https://www.amazon.com/Theological-Dictionary-New-Testament-Set/dp/0802823246). Too simple for an answer, which I also gave. Great question and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

There is ample reason to believe that Jesus used the Hebrew name "satan." The reason is that be the first c., Jewish demonology had evolved since "the satan" (ha-satan) was first used in the Book of Job. The [Jewish Encyclopedia explains](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13219-satan):

> The evolution of the theory of Satan keeps pace with the development
> of Jewish angelology and demonology. In Wisdom ii. 24 he is
> represented, with reference to Gen. iii., as the author of all evil,
> who brought death into the world; he is apparently mentioned also in
> Ecclus. (Sirach) xxi. 27, and the fact that his name does not occur in
> Daniel is doubtless due merely to chance. Satan was the seducer and
> the paramour of Eve, and was hurled from heaven together with other
> angels because of his iniquity (Slavonic Book of Enoch, xxix. 4 et
> seq.). Since that time he has been called "Satan," although previously
> he had been termed "Satanel" (ib. xxxi. 3 et seq.).

Since "Satan" was already in wide use among Jews in Jesus' time, it is probable Jesus referred to the devil by that name and that the NT uses the hellenized version of it. NT writers did [quote from the Septuagint](https://academic.oup.com/book/6258/chapter-abstract/149903383?redirectedFrom=fulltext), so it may well be that the NT adopted the convention of the LXX's translation of Job, but it could also be the case that it hellenized Satan's name in a similar way to its treatment of other Hebrew names such as Joshua/Yeshua (Iisoús) and Miriam/Maryam (Maria).

Answer (score 0):

This question is about Greek in both New and Old Testaments, so we should consider the [Septuagint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint).

### *Satan* in the Old Testament: Septuagint says "devil" via *διαβολος*:

Job (Septuagint) uses *ο διαβολος* *(ha diablos)* in both chapters [1](https://www.septuagint.bible/-/iob-kephalaio-1) and [2](https://www.septuagint.bible/-/iob-kephalaio-2). This generally means *the devil*, with a monadic or celebrity use of the definite article *the*. This means "the [one and only]" (monadic) and/or "the [well known]" (celebrity).

[1 Chronicles 21:1](https://www.septuagint.bible/-/paraleipomenon-a-kephalaio-21) (Septuagint) uses simply *διαβολος* *(diablos)* without the article "the".

[Zechariah 3](https://www.septuagint.bible/-/zacharias-kephalaio-3) (Septuagint) also uses *ο διαβολος* *(ha diablos)* with the definite article.

Then, we have comments on the Hebrew Bible from Kelly via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_in_Christianity):

> For example, in the Hebrew book of Job, one of the angels is referred to as a satan, "an adversary", but in the Greek Septuagint, which was used by the early Christians, whenever "the Satan" (Ha-Satan) appears with a definite article, it specifically refers to the individual known as the heavenly accuser whose personal name is Satan. In some cases it is unclear which is intended.

*— Kelly, Henry Ansgar (2006). Satan: A Biography. Cambridge University Press. ISBN 978-0-521-84339-3*

But, bear in mind *ha satan* isn't Greek from the Septuagint since the Septuagint uses *ha diablos*. Statements like this one from Kelly are not about the Septuagint or Greek. So, this is not a Greek language development—it is a Jewish thought development about "devil/satan" concepts.

### *Satan* in the New Testament: *Σατανᾶ* or *σατανα*

Matthew 4:10, early in the New Testament, "Satan" finally appears in Greek as *Σατανᾶ* *(Satana)* from [SBLGNT](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mat%204%3A10&version=SBLGNT) or *σατανα* *(satana)* from [WHNU](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mat%204%3A10&version=WHNU).

The problem with looking at capital letters in our Greek sources is that New Testament Koine Greek was written ALL CAPS. So, we also can't derive capitalization from our modern texts as if original. So, don't be mislead by arguments from "capital Satana" vs "lowercase satana"—there is no such difference in the original New Testament.

### What developed—name or concept?

As I research this, I don't see any *Septuagint basis* for the name "Satan" developing from Σατανᾶ in Greek. It seems to be a New Testament concept built on bilingual Jews speaking their Hebrew words in Greek.

So, the take away isn't so much the Greek words *διαβολος* vs *σατανα*, but the development of ideas from "the accuser" to "Mr. Accuser" through Hebrew and Jewish history. The concept of Satan/Devil does seem to move from being a type of being to being a specific being who earned the name.

---

Related questions that includes Hebrew or Lucifer:

- [What is the oldest manuscript evidence for the name Satan and its etymological origin?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/85434/)
- [Is Lucifer a proper name of Satan according to Isaiah 14:12?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/59388)
- [Does the word Satan ever show up in the New Testament?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/)